# Integrating firebase into standalone component

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I have a project which is a social app made with ionic angular and I want to include the firebase imports in it

```
provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())
```

The issue is that those imports should be in the app.module.ts file while the current component is a standalone component. I don't know where to put the imports as I should import:

```
import { provideFirebaseApp, getApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

Comment: Standalone components can have an imports Array in their @Component() decorator

Comment: when I put it in the imports as:
  imports: [IonicModule, ExploreContainerComponent, FormsModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())
  ],
}) 
Type 'ModuleWithProviders<FirebaseAppModule>' is not assignable to type 'readonly any[] | Type<any>'.ts(2322)
'imports' contains a ModuleWithProviders value, likely the result of a 'Module.forRoot()'-style call. These calls are not used to configure components and are not valid in standalone component imports - consider importing them in the application bootstrap instead

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#configuring-dependency-injection

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you need to provide your firebase app on application bootstrapping like this:

```
bootstrapApplication(YourComponent, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(
      provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase))
    ),
    importProvidersFrom(
      provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())
    )
  ]
});
```

Comment: the `provideFirebaseApp` etc also have an injector parameter if you need inversion of control e.g. to inject a token instead of directly using environment

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a pretty good solution. *disclaimer: I'm new to standalone*

### main.ts

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    importProvidersFrom(IonicModule.forRoot()),
    provideRouter(routes),
    importProvidersFrom(provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase))),
    importProvidersFrom(provideAnalytics(() => getAnalytics())),
    importProvidersFrom(provideAuth(() => getAuth())),
    importProvidersFrom(provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())),
    ScreenTrackingService,
    UserTrackingService,
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to clean it up but I'm using:

```
import { InjectionToken, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {
  FirebaseApp,
  initializeApp,
  provideFirebaseApp,
} from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideAuth, getAuth, connectAuthEmulator } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {
  provideFirestore,
  getFirestore,
  connectFirestoreEmulator,
  initializeFirestore,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';

export interface IFirebaseConfig {
  apiKey: string;
  authDomain: string;
  projectId: string;
  locationId: string;
  storageBucket: string;
  messagingSenderId: string;
  appId: string;
  measurementId: string;
}

export const FIREBASE_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<IFirebaseConfig>(
  'FIREBASE_CONFIG',
  {
    providedIn: 'any',
    factory: () => {
      throw new Error(`Provide FIREBASE_CONFIG`);
    },
  }
);
export const USE_EMULATORS = new InjectionToken<boolean>('USE_EMULATORS', {
  providedIn: 'any',
  factory: () => {
    throw new Error(`Provide USE_EMULATORS`);
  },
});

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    provideFirebaseApp((injector) => {
      const config = injector.get(FIREBASE_CONFIG);
      console.log(' provideFirebaseApp');
      return initializeApp(config);
    }),
    provideAuth((injector) => {
      console.log(' provideAuth');
      const app = injector.get(FirebaseApp);
      const auth = getAuth(app);
      if (injector.get(USE_EMULATORS)) {
        console.log(' using auth emulator...');
        connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://localhost:9099');
      }
      return auth;
    }),
    provideFirestore((injector) => {
      console.log(' provideFirestore');
      let firestore;
      if (injector.get(USE_EMULATORS)) {
        console.log(
          ` using firestore emulator...${
            injector.get(FIREBASE_CONFIG).projectId
          }`
        );
        // bug: experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling not picked up via `getFirestore`
        const app = injector.get(FirebaseApp);
        firestore = initializeFirestore(app, {
          experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling: true,
        });
        connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, 'localhost', 8080);
      } else {
        firestore = getFirestore();
      }
      return firestore;
    }),
  ],
})
export class FirebaseV7Module {}
```

And then including the following like a *provideFirebase()* in the providers of `bootstrapApplication`:

```
importProvidersFrom(
 FirebaseV7Module
)
```

Note you can also add providers to the router so not everything has to go onto the root provider but in this case it makes sense.

—-

In the new standalone world, instead of bootstrapping based off a module the application bootstraps based off a component in `main.ts`:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

With `appConfig` collocated with the app component in source:

`src/app/app.config.ts` example from [RealWorld Example App](https://github.com/nartc/ng-conduit):

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    { provide: ApiConfiguration, useValue: { rootUrl: environment.apiUrl } },
    provideRouter(
      [
        {
          path: '',
          loadComponent: () => import('./layout/layout.component'),
          loadChildren: () => import('./layout/layout.routes'),
        },
      ],
      withHashLocation()
    ),
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([authInterceptor()])),
 ],
};
```

Comment: Where to put the bootstrapApplication function? (in which component)

Comment: @Xyz.WebDeveloper sorry, should have been clearer. That’s the standalone bootstrap  that happens in `main.ts`. I’ll update the answer

Comment: In the main.ts the AppComponent in provided in main ts as the bootstrap. will it work with all components?

Comment: Aslo, I installed firebase using ng add @angular/fire, but my dependencies in package.json are missing firebase and fxfire. Should I install them using npm?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.5.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "4.1.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "4.7.3",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "4.1.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "4.1.1",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "4.1.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^7.0.0",
    "ionicons": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },

Comment: I think firebase and rxfire are peer dependencies so don’t need to be directly installed but the app will break fast and let you know if you need to install. In theory you can bootstrap any component you like but it’s usually best not to mess with main.ts too much until you know what you’re doing (but try it out!)

Comment: Okay, I will try the above solution and see. Question, if I don't want to include authentication of firebase, should I remove provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([authInterceptor()])) from appConfig

Comment: Example only! I’d recommend SirMany’s approach starting out (it’s really the same under the hood) but you may end up in a place similar to the above.